# Strange Pygame Error : 'need to be a pygame.Surface'

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I'm currently working on a game with Pygame and I got a strange error on a very simple program

```
import os, sys, math, time, random, pygame
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../lib')) # The program add the folder 'lib' in importable packages
import logs
from constants import *
from definitions import *

pygame.init()
background = pygame.image.load("bg1.png").convert

inProgress = True
a = 1
while inProgress:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    DrawBar(barPos, barSize, borderColor, Very_Light_Blue, (2*a)/max_a)
    a = a + 1
    if a > max_a:
        a = max_a
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                inProgess = False
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

But the traceback said me :
' lign 14 in screen(background (0,0)), 'background' need to be a Pygame.surface and not a function or dictonnary'
Kind of weird...
Can you help me ?

Comment: Is ```.convert``` supposed to be ```.convert()```?

Comment: I,m freaking stupid xD

Comment: Easy mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. You missed the parentheses after the call of the `convert` method:

<s>`background = pygame.image.load("bg1.png").convert`</s>

```py
background = pygame.image.load("bg1.png").convert()
```

Comment: Please don't answer ```typo``` questions, commenting would rather be a better idea

Comment: @GameDev I have voted to close and this is a communiti wiki answer